# How to get values of previous fragment when return from second fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

In my Android app, I have a fragment A and fragment B.
frag A has two edit text and a button(to go to frag B)
When I enter some value in frag A edit text, and go to frag B, press back from frag B to A, Edit text values are getting removed. I need to save them.

Comment: You are talking about Android development, right?

Comment: yes, android kotlin

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this [SharedViewModel](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#0). You'll be able to keep your data or even pass it between these Fragments. You can use [SavedStateHandle](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate) if you want to keep values without sharing data between Fragments. You can also use [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore?gclid=Cj0KCQiAnaeNBhCUARIsABEee8XEXak08c_Q97u3ogmKMB524VHcynYVCIX6V0kOGDqo9mdTltxfhwkaAiHIEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) if you don't have ViewModel's.